# How to add HTML elements in to JavaScript object and use in react

Tags: reactjs, javascript-objects, htmlelements

This is code in a JavaScript object

```
const AlbumDetails = [
{
    name: '<i class="fas fa-check">Basic</i>',
    price: '',
    details: [],
},
{ name: '<i class="fas fa-check">Intermediate</i>', price: '', details: [] },
{ name: '<i class="fas fa-check">Pro</i>', price: '', details: [] },
{ name: '<i class="fas fa-check">Ultimate</i>', price: '', details: [] },
];

export default AlbumDetails;
```

and I want to use this object like

```
const PriceCard = (props) => {
<div className="p-box">
                    
    <div className="p-content">
        <h2>{props.AlbumDetails[0].name}</h2>
        <h4>{props.AlbumDetails[0].price}</h4>
        
        
    </div>
</div>
}
```

so on.
In the browser, it shows `<i class="fas fa-check">Basic</i>`, but I want only the icon and name "Basic" only.
So how it could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML string can be inserted using [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml):

```
<h2 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.AlbumDetails[0].name }} />
```

Note: you need to be satisfied that the HTML is safe (i.e is not formed from user input), otherwise you could open yourself up to XSS.

Comment: Thank you a lot, It's work. you save my day

Comment: Does this try to manually insert the tag in DOM?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of keeping the entire JSX in the Array, keep only the words in array

```
const AlbumDetails = [
{
    name: 'Basic',
    price: '',
    details: [],
},
{ name: 'Intermediate', price: '', details: [] },
{ name: 'Pro', price: '', details: [] },
{ name: 'Ultimate', price: '', details: [] },
```

And keep the JSX in the component and instead only access the content like this

```
const PriceCard = (props) => {
<div className="p-box">
                    
    <div className="p-content">
        <h2><i class="fas fa-check">{props.AlbumDetails[0].name}</i></h2>
        <h4>{props.AlbumDetails[0].price}</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, but I have to reuse that priceCard component, Thank You.!!

Answer (score 1):

From your example, I see you are trying to show multiple elements of the same data source. You can use JavaScript map() function so that you don't have refer them using indices and avoid repeated lines of code. Please refer the below code.

```
const AlbumDetails = [
  {
    name: '<i class="fas fa-check">Basic</i>',
    price: "",
    details: []
  },
  { name: '<i class="fas fa-check">Intermediate</i>', price: "", details: [] },
  { name: '<i class="fas fa-check">Pro</i>', price: "", details: [] },
  { name: '<i class="fas fa-check">Ultimate</i>', price: "", details: [] }
];

const PriceCard = (props) => (
  <div className="p-box">
    <div className="p-content">
      {props.AlbumDetails.map((album) => (
        <div key={album.name}>
          <h2>{album.name}</h2>
          <h4>{album.price}</h4>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

You can read more about this [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: Yeah, I will check that also.. Thank you.